# Samba4 DNS - clear old DNS records

Tags: debian, dns, isc-dhcpd, samba4

Creating AD 2003 domain using Samba-4.3.4 with internal DNS. ISC-DHCP as a server. On Debian.

DNS updates comes only from DHCP-server.

What tool do I have to use to clear old DNS records, or what mechanizm is used to detect and (maybe) automatically clear such records?